# Create a list of values in cms converted from feet inch

Tags: java, android

I have a list of values of height in feet inch. If user change the height metric from feet inch to centimeters then the list show all the values in centimeters.

Here is my code for the height in feet inch:

```
 HorizontalPicker heightPicker = (HorizontalPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.heightPicker);


    final ArrayList<CharSequence> heightArray = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    for (int index = 3; index < 7; index++) {
        for (int index1 = 0; index1 < 12; index1++) {
            heightArray.add(index + "." + index1 + "\"");
            if (index == 6 && index1 == 4) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    CharSequence[] height1 = new CharSequence[heightArray.size()];
    final CharSequence[] height = heightArray.toArray(height1);

    heightPicker.setValues(height);

    heightPicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(new HorizontalPicker.OnItemSelected() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int index) {
            double heightInt = 0;
            try {
                heightInt = Double.parseDouble(trimLastChar(height[index].toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            userProfile.setHeight(heightInt);
        }
    });
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I dont know how to convert this list of values to centimeters.

Comment: Do you mean the ArrayList heightArray?